# kubectl how to rename a context

Tags: kubectl

I have many contexts, one for staging, one for production, and many for dev clusters. Copy and pasting the default cluster names is tedious and hard, especially over time. How can I rename them to make context switching easier?

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Renaming contexts is easy!

```
$ kubectl config rename-context old-name new-name
```

Confirm the change by

```
$ kubectl config get-contexts
```

Answer (score 22):

If you are using [kubectx](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubectx) try

```
kubectx new-context-name=old-context-name
```